# How to make ajax long polling with php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, long-polling

I made the php code which it gets rows from Asks table that are not read :

```
$sqlanum = "SELECT id FROM asks WHERE answer='' AND profile='1' AND askdate>now()";
$queryanum = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlanum);
$rowanum = mysqli_num_rows($queryanum);
```

I am not familiar with Ajax long-polling , I just read about it few things and after searching for simple Ajax long-polling examples i made something like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "chkasks.php",

        async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
        cache: false,
        timeout: 50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ /* called when request completes */
            //addmsg("new", data);
            setTimeout(chkAsks, 1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(chkAsks, 3000);
        }
    });
};
```

but I don't know how I can make it in a loop and break if there is results and continue looping i there is no results...

Comment: From what I tried a few years ago, many popular web servers had issues with this, along with browsers, since they wouldn't flush the data until a certain limit. I hope someone can bring more insight since I'm also interested. Also I think what you are referring to is called "Comet".

Comment: thanks for your reply .... but i think Facebook is using long-polling

Comment: If I understand well, you want to check every X seconds the value of `$rowanum`, and change the behavior of your client according to its value ?

Comment: no i want to check every 1 second the value of $rowanum but dont return anything unless there is a value for $rowanum

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP, you can add `echo $rowanum;`, it will send the value of `$rowanum` in the `data` variable, in your JavaScript.

Then, you can change your success callback to :

```
/* .... */
success : function(data) {
    if(data == 0) {
         setTimeout(chkAsks, 1000); //Where chkAsks is the function from which the ajax request is fired
    } else {
          console.log('$rowanum=' + data);
    }
} 
/* .... */
```

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: thanks but in the php file what it would do if there is no data i dont want the javascript do anything if there is no data...

Comment: By there is no data, you mean $rowanum = 0 ? Because `mysqli_num_rows` always returns a value. So you can either do in your PHP script `if ($rowanum != 0) { echo $rowanum; }` and check if data is empty (`if (data == "") { }`) in your JS or always echo `$rowanum`'s value and check in your JS if it is equal to 0.

Comment: if the $rowanum = 0 and the php keep returning 0 that means i am using short-polling and this cause the server to get down ... and i want to make long-polling so it doen't return anything if $rowanum = 0 and it keeps looping...

Comment: I think you have to handle it server side. You could loop on your SQL query while $rowanum != 0, but you need to pause (with sleep()) your script between every query (otherwise your server will consume all CPU and make other requests very slow). If $rowanum != 0, you exit the loop and print its value. That way ajax will wait until $rowanum is != 0. I've never done that, but I suppose it works...